# CentOS 5.10 Yum Packages won't update/upgrade

Tags: linux, centos, php, phpmyadmin

I've just used yum to install PhpMyAdmin and it installed version 2.11.11.3-2.el5 which is completely out of date since version 4 is out.

I've tried running `yum update phpmyadmin` but I receive `No Packages marked for Update` I've also tried `yum upgrade` but I get `No Packages marked for Update`.

This is the same for any package I try to update, such as PHP which is for some reason running PHP version 5.1.6.

I've also tried running package-cleanup but I've had no luck with that either.

Here's the contents of my /etc/yum.conf if that helps:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug
exclude=kernel*

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h

installonly_limit = 5
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: `yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin` appears to work, as it finds phpMyAdmin version 4, but I receive a lot of errors about mysql conflicting with versions.

Comment: Fixed it by erasing mysql, then running the above command. :)